# How to dress suitably for Jungfrau mountain sightseeing trip?

Tags: sightseeing, switzerland, weather-and-climate, clothing, jungfrau-region

I have planned to travel sightseeing at Jungfrau mountain in Switzerland.

Since I have checked with many weather forecast website on my trip date, they said the weather probably be cloudy, partly sunny and the temperature is about -5 °C.

I came from the warm climate (always hot) country, Thailand. So, I am not sure about how to dress suitably for the weather like this.

So, I would like to ask the suggestion for the way of dressing. Moreover, Do I need to bring any medicine to prevent or cure in some case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You did not really specify where exactly you want to go, but since you mentioned Jungfrau region, I assume that you're talking about [Jungfraujoch](http://www.jungfraujoch.ch/).

As Kathryn Hill already mentioned, it can get very cold up there. But this is not only the case in winter. Since it is around 3500 meters above sea level, it is cold year round up there. Even now in autumn, it can get as low as -20° C. And even in the highest summer season, the temperature might be around 0°C. So you should really be prepared for cold weather during the whole year.

I would recommend that you particularly focus on wearing warm shoes that are water-proofed so that you won't get wet socks. Nothing is nastier than wet-socks when it's cold out there. Furthermore, bring a warm cap with you and I'm sure you won't regret if you also bring gloves with you. I personally would also wear a warm jacket, especially one that stops the wind. If it's cold and windy, you will easily suffer from [wind chill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chill). Trousers are not so important if you don't plan to lie or sit in the snow. In this case a normal jeans (if you prefer with long underwear as Kathryn Hill mentioned) is enough. Otherwise, I would recommend a waterproofed trouser.

Additionally, you should not forget to wear sunglasses. If the weather is nice, the sun is very bright and since on Jungfraujoch, there is snow all year round, the sunlight will be reflected heavily. For the same reason, also make sure to bring your sunscreen with you.

If you plan to walk in the snow, you could also borrow gaiters to prevent snow getting in your shoes.

Concerning your medical question: There are [medical hints](http://www.jungfrau.ch/en/sommer/tourism/travel-information/medical-tips/) on the Jungfraujoch homepage. The biggest danger is altitude sickness. Altitude sickness is caused by the decreasing air pressure and oxygen level in higher altitudes. However, normally, the first symptoms of altitude sickness will not be visible before 6-12 hours, so, normally, this shouldn't be a problem in your case. However, I would recommend to read the medical hints to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 9):

You'll definitely want a pair of sturdy water-resistant hiking boots.  If possible, break them in before your trip.  And some thick, warm socks.

Coming from a hot country and going to a climate where it's -5 °C, you might want some long underwear to wear under your clothing when you're outside.

You didn't specify what dates you'll be there or how active you plan to be outdoors.  I'm going to assume you'll be there in the winter due to your mention of the low temperature, so you might want to read up on winter hiking gear.  Here are some links for you to peruse:

1. http://dealnews.com/features/What-to-Wear-for-a-Winter-Hike-from-Head-to-Toe/516406.html
2. http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/winter-camping.html

Regarding medicine, Switzerland is not really a country where you have to worry about getting sick in general.  If you have some sort of minor ailment while there (headache, runny nose, stomachache) you can easily buy medicine at the nearest pharmacy ("apotheke" in German, look for the green cross +)

You might experience some altitude sickness as you adjust, depending on how high up you go, but stay hydrated and don't push yourself too quickly, and you'll acclimate to the altitude.

Answer (score 0):

Some great advice here. The only things I think are worth adding are:

1. It's not just about how warm your clothes are, dressing in layers would be highly recommended. It gives you a full range of flexibility for all weathers. And each layer deals with a different issue (sweat, insulation, protection from wind/rain).
2. Stay hydrated. It's quite easy to remember to take on lots of fluid in hot climates. But it's quite easy to forget in cold climates. So it's worth considering trying to kill two birds with one stone and take a thermos with something hot as it will be both hydrating and warming.
3. Keep taking on calories. You burn a lot of energy in the cold, especially when you're active. Snacks are a must, and don't feel guilty about taking something that's really fatty or sugary!

Useful references:

https://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/layering-basics.html
https://www.summitmedicalgroup.com/news/living-well/stay-hydrated-cold-weather/
https://effortlessoutdoors.com/winter-camping-how-to/